# How to save Data to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I ve been working on a phonebook program on eclipse java

but and idk how to save information from a `textfield` to `mysql` and then be able use it in search, such as writing the name and finding all the info of the specific contact
I also want to save it to my sql
thats my code:

```
public class Phone {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField firstfield;
    private JTextField phonefield;
    private JTextField emailfield;
    private JTextField lastfield;
    private JPanel MainScreen; 
    private JPanel newcontact;
    private JPanel searchscreen;



    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Phone window = new Phone();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Phone() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        final JPanel MainScreen = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(MainScreen, "name_6058038854379");
        MainScreen.setLayout(null);
        MainScreen.setVisible(true);

        final JPanel newcontact = new JPanel();
        newcontact.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(newcontact, "name_791613670731");
        newcontact.setVisible(false);

        final JPanel searchscreen = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(searchscreen, "name_6068807854350");
        searchscreen.setVisible(false);


        JButton newrecord = new JButton("New Record");
        newrecord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                newcontact.setVisible(true);
                MainScreen.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
        newrecord.setBounds(63, 99, 116, 52);
        MainScreen.add(newrecord);

        JButton Search = new JButton("Search");
        Search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                searchscreen.setVisible(true);
                newcontact.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        Search.setBounds(243, 99, 102, 52);
        MainScreen.add(Search);

        JLabel myphonebook = new JLabel("   My Phonebook");
        myphonebook.setBounds(162, 44, 102, 14);
        MainScreen.add(myphonebook);



        JLabel first = new JLabel("First Name:");
        first.setBounds(118, 83, 66, 14);
        newcontact.add(first);

        JLabel last = new JLabel("Last Name:");
        last.setBounds(118, 108, 66, 14);
        newcontact.add(last);

        JLabel Phone = new JLabel("Phone:");
        Phone.setBounds(118, 143, 66, 14);
        newcontact.add(Phone);

        JLabel Emailadress = new JLabel("Email Adress:");
        Emailadress.setBounds(118, 180, 66, 14);
        newcontact.add(Emailadress);

        firstfield = new JTextField();
        firstfield.setColumns(10);
        firstfield.setBounds(220, 80, 86, 20);
        newcontact.add(firstfield);

        lastfield = new JTextField();
        lastfield.setColumns(10);
        lastfield.setBounds(220, 108, 86, 20);
        newcontact.add(lastfield);



        phonefield = new JTextField();
        phonefield.setColumns(10);
        phonefield.setBounds(220, 140, 86, 20);
        newcontact.add(phonefield);


        emailfield = new JTextField();
        emailfield.setColumns(10);
        emailfield.setBounds(220, 177, 86, 20);
        newcontact.add(emailfield);



        JLabel lblNewContact = new JLabel("New Contact");
        lblNewContact.setBounds(166, 30, 86, 14);
        newcontact.add(lblNewContact);

        JButton Save = new JButton("Save");
        Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String firstname=firstfield.getText();
                String lastname=lastfield.getText();
                String phonenumber=phonefield.getText();
                String emailadress=emailfield.getText();



            }
        });
        Save.setBounds(81, 232, 89, 23);
        newcontact.add(Save);

        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newcontact.setVisible(false);
                MainScreen.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        cancel.setBounds(283, 232, 89, 23);
        newcontact.add(cancel);



        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, "name_6081212161880");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting project, let us know if you have a question!

Comment: hey @Shadow I have a question. I am kind of new to programming and I wanted to know if preparedStmt.execute(); will bring the information mysql and show it on the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this into your savecommand. You should only create a database an table and change the uppercased words.

```
 try
        {
          // create a mysql database connection
          String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
          String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://LOCATION/DATABASE"; 
          Class.forName(myDriver);
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

          // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

          // the mysql insert statement
          String query = " insert into TABLE (first_name, last_name, phone_number, email_adress)"
            + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

          // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
          PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
          preparedStmt.setString (1, firstname);
          preparedStmt.setString (2, lastname);
          preparedStmt.setString (3, phonenumber);
          preparedStmt.setString (4, emailadress);

          // execute the preparedstatement
          preparedStmt.execute();

          conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.err.println("Got an exception!");
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
```

Comment: so i put this under the actionlistener of thye save button and its gonna work ??

Comment: its giving an error because PreparedStatement and Calendar and Connection cant be resolved to a type and DriverManager cant be resolved at all plz help @Matti9811

Comment: OK so it worked but i got an exception and this code org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver